# Android Step Counter not working, not appearing in SensorManager

Tags: java, android, mobile, frontend, android-sensors

im trying to make a simple step counter in Android, im currently using Oreo and emulating with Pixel 2 API 29. The problem is that its simply not working, when i call the sensorManager there is no sensor listed neither for STEP_COUNTER or STEP_DETECTOR. I followed different tutorials step by step and didnt work. Does anyone know what could be the problem? Here is my code and manifest, and the list im talking about,

**My activity StepsActivity.java**

```
public class StepsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    SensorManager sm;
    Sensor sensor;
    TextView tv_steps_count;
    int counter=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_steps);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            //ask for permission
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION},Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        }

        tv_steps_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_steps_count);

        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if(sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null){
            sensor = (Sensor) sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        }else if(sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)!=null){
            sensor =(Sensor) sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        }

        findViewById(R.id.backBTN).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            tv_steps_count.setText(""+sensorEvent.values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        stop();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        start();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void start() {
        sm.registerListener(this, sensor, sm.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    private void stop() {
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

**My manifest** (just the parts of it which that have to do with this)

```
...
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
        android:required="true"/>
   <uses-feature
       android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector"
       android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
...
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector"
        android:required="true"/>
...
```

And a screenshot picturing the problem on debugger
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the emulator does not support the STEP_COUNTER or STEP_DETECTOR. You will need to test this feature on a real device that has hardware support for those two sensors.

Comment: Hello, its not working in my samsung device either. I get an extended list with 25 sensors but any of them are for the step counter or the step detector

Comment: Not all devices have all of the sensors. I know most high and mid range devices have the two sensors you are looking for. For example my Galaxy S20, and Pixel 2, 3 have both of those sensors. You are unlikely to find those sensors on budget phones.